# How to create a 3D matrix of values in VB.NET?

Tags: matrix, 3d

In 2D I write:
Dim matr2D(,) As Integer = { {10, 20, 30}, {11, 21, 31}, {12, 22, 32} }.

In 3D?

Answer (score 0):

Found:

Dim matr3D(, ,) As Integer = { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } }

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx